# Как разбить код на 2 потока?

Tags: java, многопоточность, оптимизация

Есть программа, которая пишет в txt-файл гос.номера 99 регионов страны. Моя задача ускорить работу, путем деления его выполнение на 2 потока, каждый из них должен писать свои госномера в отдельный файл. Т.е. должно быть 2 потока и два файла для записи.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Loader extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("res/numbers.txt");

        char letters[] = {'У', 'К', 'Е', 'Н', 'Х', 'В', 'А', 'Р', 'О', 'С', 'М', 'Т'};

        for (int regionCode = 1; regionCode < 100; regionCode++) {

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int number = 1; number < 1000; number++) {
                for (char firstLetter : letters) {
                    for (char secondLetter : letters) {
                        for (char thirdLetter : letters) {
                            
                            builder.append(firstLetter);
                            builder.append(padNumber(number, 3));
                            builder.append(secondLetter);
                            builder.append(thirdLetter);
                            builder.append(padNumber(regionCode, 2));
                            builder.append("\n");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            writer.write(builder.toString());
        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
    }

    private static String padNumber(int number, int numberLength) {

        StringBuilder builderPad = new StringBuilder();
        String numberStr = Integer.toString(number);
        int padSize = numberLength - numberStr.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < padSize; i++) {
            builderPad.append(numberStr = '0' + numberStr);
        }
        return numberStr;
    }
}
```

Comment: А "свои госномера" для потока, это какие? Перепишите чтобы последовательно писался один и второй файлы. После этого все просто будет распараллелить.

Comment: HDD/SSD обычно один, параллельная запись (если затык в ней) только замедлит работу

Comment: Свои госномера, это к примеру первый поток номера с кодом региона от 1 до 50, а второй от 51  до 99 региона.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А почему именно в 2? Я бы вообще отдал это на откуп стримам, так проще и точно быстрее раза в три будет

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Loader {

    private final static char letters[] = {'У', 'К', 'Е', 'Н', 'Х', 'В', 'А', 'Р', 'О', 'С', 'М', 'Т'};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        write("res/numbers1.txt", 1, 50);
        write("res/numbers2.txt", 50, 100);

        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
    }

    private static void write(String fileName, int startIndex, int endIndex) throws Exception {
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName)) {
            IntStream.range(startIndex, endIndex).parallel()
                    .mapToObj(regionCode -> process(regionCode))
                    .forEach(writer::write);
        }
    }

    private static String process(int regionCode) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int number = 1; number < 1000; number++) {
            for (char firstLetter : letters) {
                for (char secondLetter : letters) {
                    for (char thirdLetter : letters) {

                        builder.append(firstLetter);
                        builder.append(padNumber(number, 3));
                        builder.append(secondLetter);
                        builder.append(thirdLetter);
                        builder.append(padNumber(regionCode, 2));
                        builder.append("\n");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    private static String padNumber(int number, int numberLength) {

        StringBuilder builderPad = new StringBuilder();
        String numberStr = Integer.toString(number);
        int padSize = numberLength - numberStr.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < padSize; i++) {
            builderPad.append(numberStr = '0' + numberStr);
        }
        return numberStr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, я протестил, работает быстрее процентов на 30, это то, что нужно, а как грамотно разбить запись в 2 файла?,  например, что бы номера с регионом от 1 до 50, писались в один файл, а номера от 51 до 99 в другой.

Comment: не знаю, почему у вас только на 30 процентов... на моей машине почти в 3 раза быстрее. что касается 2 файлов, то тут все довольно просто. смотрите исправленный ответ

Comment: parallel() - штука та еще... То что разный прирост производительности показала - не удивительно. Могло еще и медленнее стать. Распараллеливать стримы нужно очень аккуратно и точно понимая зачем это делается и что  при этом происходит, иначе можно нарваться на такие вещи, что все летает на локалке и встает намертво в проде...

Comment: А нас не смущает, что в файлах регионы могут идти не по порядку?

Comment: про порядок в условии задания ничего не сказано

Comment: Да, отлично, пишет в 2 файла, спасибо.